# How to use CLion with Qt Online Installer?

Tags: qt, cmake, clion

Namely, how can I specify which directories should the cmake build search on my computer without modifying the `CMakeLists.txt` for everybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/vadi/Programs/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/` does the trick (change accordingly to your location).